# How do I empty an input value with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I’m trying to make a modal dialog with images where you can select multiple images. I need to get values from an input and then to empty it, but I cannot empty the input. I tried `.val('')` and `.val(null)`, but neither worked for me.

Here is the full code:

```
$("#hdselect").click(function(){
        $(".modal").html("");

        $.post('mediaservice.php',{hd:'ok',images:$("#hdimages").val()},function(data){
            $(".modal").append(data);
        });
        $(".modal").dialog({
            'modal':true,
            'title':"Click the image to select",
            'width':960,
            'height':600,
            'resizable':false,
            'show': {effect: 'drop', direction: "up"},
            'buttons': {"Ok": function() {  
                    var hd=Array();
                    var hdval=$("#hdimages").val();
                    $("#hdimages").attr('value',' ');
                    $("input[name='hd[]']:checked").each(function(){
                        hd.push($(this).val());
                    });
                    if(hdval!=''){
                        hdval=hdval+","+hd;
                    }else{
                        hdval=hd;
                    }                        
                    $("#hdimages").val(hdval);
                    var images=$("#hdimages").val();
                    $.post('mediaservice.php',{getHd:images},function(data){
                        $("#imgthumbBase").append(data);
                    });
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

The idea is that the user clicks a button and a  modal dialog opens with multiple images and checkboxes. At this point I need to get the values from an input, and then clear it.

Comment: ```$('input').val('')``` will do the job.  **Live Example** - http://jsfiddle.net/fQMmp/1/

Did you mean something related to images?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do but $('#inputid').val(''); will definitely clear the input's value. Looking at your code, I cannot actually see .val('') anywhere?

Comment: Please provide some more context, it's not possible to tell why your code does not work otherwise.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that, but the code you posted doesn't make sense. You clear the val just to set it again and then you retrieve the value again although you have stored that value in a variable.

Comment: @VitKos take a look at this: http://pastebin.com/EEdQEmwY It does the same as your code with less fuzz. Also you should store your dom-elements into a variable: `var $hdimages = $("#hdimages");`

Comment: @TJVanToll Your jsfiddle example doesn't work. I can still see a value in the input field. Not sure why this isn't working for me but I remember being able to just do .val('') as well.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You could try:

```
$('input.class').removeAttr('value');
$('#inputID').removeAttr('value');
```

Comment: @VitKos I guess it's another problem in your code and you jsut accidently made it work...

Comment: @Christoph maybe. so I have asked the comunity to show me that.

Comment: This didn't work but .val("") worked for me. Including them both just in case the other doesn't work.

Comment: Wait - how is this the accepted answer? I just tried it and it did not work for me. Are you sure this code is correct?

Comment: As of HTML5 and 2017 - Chrome at least no longer adds a value attr. This code no longer works.

Answer (score 156):

To make values empty you can do the following:

```
 $("#element").val('');
```

To get the selected value you can do:

```
var value = $("#element").val();
```

Where `#element` is the id of the element you wish to select.

Comment: This makes value "" and not NULL.

Comment: @user1032531 - the question is how to empty an input value with jQuery and not how to assign a `null` value to the element. Please read the question properly before you down vote my answer.

Comment: Maybe user1032531 was commeting on your first phrase *To make values null you can do...* maybe its more clear to write  *To empty values you can do...*

Answer (score 37):

A better way is:

```
$("#element").val(null);
```

Comment: As of HTML5 and 2017 - Chrome at least no longer adds a value attr. So this is the only one that works in Chrome. Haven't tested other browsers.

Answer (score 17):

Usual way to empty textbox using jquery is:

```
$('#txtInput').val('');
```

If above code is not working than please check that you are able to
get the input element.

```
console.log($('#txtInput')); // should return element in the console.
```

If still facing the same problem, please post your code.

Answer (score 8):

Another way is:

```
$('#element').attr('value', '');
```

Comment: it doesn't reset the value if the text is written on input field.because the value won't be inside value attr.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.reset').on('click',function(){
           $('#upload input, #upload select').each(
                function(index){  
                    var input = $(this);
                    if(input.attr('type')=='text'){
                        document.getElementById(input.attr('id')).value = null;
                    }else if(input.attr('type')=='checkbox'){
                        document.getElementById(input.attr('id')).checked = false;
                    }else if(input.attr('type')=='radio'){
                        document.getElementById(input.attr('id')).checked = false;
                    }else{
                        document.getElementById(input.attr('id')).value = '';
                        //alert('Type: ' + input.attr('type') + ' -Name: ' + input.attr('name') + ' -Value: ' + input.val());
                    }
                }
            );
        });
```

Comment: by using the above snippet, you can reset the entire form, which may contain input fields, checkboxes, radio buttons and selection fields. We can set all those type of default values..

Answer (score 2):

For me this was the best way to solve this:

`$('yourElementName').val(null);`