# Php productcode Entered Probelm

Tags: php, ajax

if i enter the correct product code relavent  details should show.if i remove the productcode details should remove. i attached the screenshot image below.
if i remove the productcode still details should shown. what i tried so far i attached below.
[image]

```
    function getProductcode() {
        $("#barcode").empty();
        $("#barcode").keyup(function(e) {
            var q = $("#barcode").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "get_product.php",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: { barcode: $("#barcode").val() },
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data != null) {

                        is_product = true;
                        $("#pname").val(data[0].p_name);
                        $("#pro_price").val(data[0].retail_price);
                        $("#qty").focus();
                        $('#barcode').parent('div').removeClass('has-error');
                        $('#price').html('');
                    }

                    else
                    {

                        $('#barcode').parent('div').addClass('has-error');
                        is_product = false;
                        $("#pname").val('');
                        $("#pro_price").val('');

                        $('#qty').val('1');
                    }




        });
}
```

html

```
        <td>
                    <div class="focusguard" id="focusguard-1" tabindex="1"></div>
                    <input type="text" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="barcode" id="barcode" name="barcode"  required>
                </td>
                <td>
                <label id="pro_name" name="pname" id="pname"></label>
                 <input  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="barcode" id="pname" name="pname" disabled>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control pro_price" id="pro_price" name="pro_price"
                       placeholder="price" disabled>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" class="form-control pro_price" id="qty" name="qty"
                       placeholder="qty" min="1" value="1"  required>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="total_cost" id="total_cost" name="total_cost" disabled>
            </td>
```

Comment: post your html as well .

Comment: i edited the html code sir

Comment: i edited the code sir

Comment: check if your input have some value or not i.e : `if($(#barcode).val().length === 0 ){ //clear all input }` to clear values from other inputs check  [how-do-i-empty-an-input-value-with-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754874/how-do-i-empty-an-input-value-with-jquery)

Comment: ya.ok sir. but if i the enter the correct product details  shown then enter the wrong one details removed . ex if enter 1111 details shown after i add extra 1 details should removed

Comment: You can handle this as well , if user will type wrong values you will not get any `response` back from your php page ,so your `else` part will get executed in your success function.. just empty your input field there i.e : `$("#yourinputid").val('');`

Comment: i edited the code above sir but not working

Comment: yes if no value match data should shown empty

Comment: if no value matched , what does `data` in success function have in it ? is it empty or not ? put an `alert("in");` in your else part .. and check if it show or not .

Comment: if no value matched shown empty sir. then if the values matched show the relavent data then if i removed the product still shown details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198770/discussion-between-swati-and-nishan-kishan).